# I really need close the sessionFactory?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

To resolve my problem I use this code below. But I dont think this is right...

```
HibernateFactory.buildSessionFactory();
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        HibernateFactory.closeFactory();
    }
});
```

Thats my dependencies 
[Jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmLjR.png)

And my hibernate.cfg

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>   
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ClinicaVet?UseTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">jailbreak</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Disable the second level cache -->
        <property 

name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internall.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2dd1">update</property>
        <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Agendamento.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Animal.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Cliente.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Examinacao.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Exame.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Vacinacao.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Notificacoes.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Vacina.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Atendimento.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/arthurpdj/entity/Pagamento.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>     </hibernate-configuration>
```

And My HibernateUtil class ( I already try to without ServiceRegistry.. same problem.. )

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory factory = null;
private static Configuration conf;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try{
        conf = new Configuration();
        conf.configure("com/arthurpdj/database/hibernate.cfg.xml");
                    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            conf.getProperties()).build();

        System.out.println("Configurou");

        factory = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        System.out.println("construi");

        return factory;
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }

}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    if(factory ==null) {
        factory = buildSessionFactory();


    }
    return factory; 
}

}
```

Log

```
fev 02, 2017 3:05:14 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.7.Final}
fev 02, 2017 3:05:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
fev 02, 2017 3:05:14 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
fev 02, 2017 3:05:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
fev 02, 2017 3:05:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ClinicaVet?UseTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC]
fev 02, 2017 3:05:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
fev 02, 2017 3:05:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
fev 02, 2017 3:05:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Thu Feb 02 15:05:16 BRST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
fev 02, 2017 3:05:16 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Main Class

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/FXMLLogin.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 424, 331);

            primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Clinica Veterinária BarraVet");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            HibernateFactory.buildSessionFactory();
            primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {


        HibernateFactory.closeFactory();
    }
});


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post what issues are you facing??like the error logs or something

Comment: If i dont close the session factory the application do not terminate

Comment: Ok.Post your main class I can show you where to make changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Akshay, thanks for trying. I solved my problem using the c3p0 connection pool

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize using this:

```
{ 
//creating configuration object  
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  

    //creating seession factory object  
    SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  

    //creating session object  
    Session session=factory.openSession();  

    //creating transaction object  
    Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  

    //Your code of reading/writing to database here.....


    t.commit();//transaction is committed  
    session.close();  

    System.out.println("successful transaction");  

}  
}
```

Thats the safest method...Hope this helps

Comment: even before a transaction.. i cant terminate my program. And can u help me  with this mapping files?

Comment: Yes.. Make sure you make the changes first. Also post your mapping files

Comment: As I told u.. even if i didnt make any transaction my program do not terminate. I use this code without transactions and return Null Pointer.. because there is no session open.. and i cant terminate it

Comment: please. Help me

Comment: Yeah..you will need to open the session in a cleaner way..I'll post a code how to initialize it

Comment: @Arthur..go through the code and initialize it as above.